# Is it possible to automatically infer the class_weight from flow_from_directory in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I have an imbalanced multi-class dataset and I want to use the `class_weight` argument from `fit_generator` to give weights to the classes according to the number of images of each class. I'm using `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory` to load the dataset from a directory.

Is it possible to directly infer the `class_weight` argument from the `ImageDataGenerator` object?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why can't you just compute it once?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just figured out a way of achieving this.

```
from collections import Counter
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(...)

counter = Counter(train_generator.classes)                          
max_val = float(max(counter.values()))       
class_weights = {class_id : max_val/num_images for class_id, num_images in counter.items()}                     

model.fit_generator(...,
                    class_weight=class_weights)
```

`train_generator.classes` is a list of classes for each image.
`Counter(train_generator.classes)` creates a counter of the number of images in each class.

Note that these weights may not be good for convergence, but you can use it as a base for other type of weighting based on occurrence.

*This answer was inspired by: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1875#issuecomment-273752868*

Comment: but train_generator.classes only returns a list of classes, like a set, no?

Comment: It returns a list of classes for each image. For instance, if we have three images, the first two are from class 1 and the last one is from class 0, `train_generator.classes` equals `[1, 1, 0]`.

Comment: Indeed, just went to see the source code :) Good job

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Can you elaborate what you mean by "these weights may not be good for convergence"?

Comment: But how to do this in numpy, pythor or tensorflow (i.e. when image label are numpy array)?

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, you can simply do:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import numpy as np

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
               'balanced',
                np.unique(train_generator.classes), 
                train_generator.classes)
```

You can then set (as per comment above):

```
model.fit_generator(..., class_weight=class_weights)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried both solutions and the `sklearn.utils.class_weight`
 one gives better accuracy though I am not sure why. They do not both yield the same class weights.

Comment: If you look at the ratio of weights of classes in each case, it is the same.

Comment: How much of a difference did you get? @David Brown

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the article [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data), a good way to assign class weights is to use:

```
(1 / class_count) * (total_count/2)
```

Thus, slightly modifying the method suggested above by Fábio Perez:

```
counter = Counter(train_generator.classes)
total = float(sum(counter.values()))
class_weight = {class_id : (1/num_images)*(total)/2.0 for class_id, num_images in counter.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code suggested by Pasha Dembo works pretty well. However, you should transform it in a dictionary before inserting in the model_fit generator:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight import numpy as np

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
           'balanced',
            np.unique(train_generator.classes), 
            train_generator.classes)

train_class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
model.fit_generator(..., class_weight=train_class_weights)
```

Alternatively, you can simply do:

```
 from sklearn.utils import class_weight import numpy as np
 
 class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
                'balanced',
                 np.unique(train_generator.classes), 
                 train_generator.classes) You can then set (as per comment above):
 
 model.fit_generator(..., class_weight=class_weights)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import numpy as np
class_weights = dict(zip(np.unique(traingen.classes),class_weight.compute_class_weight(
                        class_weight = 'balanced',
                        classes = np.unique(traingen.classes), 
                        y = traingen.classes)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

April 2023 version. Ended up using this:

```
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight

unique_classes = np.unique(ds_train.classes)
# "If ‘balanced’, class weights will be given by n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))."
class_weights = compute_class_weight("balanced", classes=unique_classes, y=ds_train.classes)
class_weight = {class_id: weight for class_id, weight in zip(unique_classes, class_weights)}

model.fit(..., class_weight=class_weight)
```