# How can I assign a class_weight in Keras in a simple way?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Can anyone tell me what is the simplest way to apply `class_weight` in Keras when the dataset is unbalanced please?

I only have two classes in my target.

Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

The `class_weight` parameter of the `fit()` function is a dictionary mapping classes to a weight value.

Lets say you have 500 samples of class 0 and 1500 samples of class 1 than you feed in class_weight = {0:3 , 1:1}. That gives class 0 three times the weight of class 1.

`train_generator.classes` gives you the proper class names for your weighting.

If you want to calculate this programmatically you can use scikit-learn´s [sklearn.utils.compute_class_weight()](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py).

The function looks at the distribution of labels and produces weights to equally penalize under or over-represented classes in the training set.

See also this useful thread here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1875

And this thread might also be of help: [Is it possible to automatically infer the class_weight from flow_from_directory in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586475/is-it-possible-to-automatically-infer-the-class-weight-from-flow-from-directory)

Comment: Finally a clear example! Nowhere else does it seem to say whether the weighting scales up or down

Comment: This should be the top answer - it answers what the question was asking (about Keras, not scikit-learn) and also provides docs & explanation.

Answer (score 22):

Using class_weight from sklearn kit.

Im also using this method to deal with the imbalance data

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
class_weight = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced'
                                               ,np.unique(Y_train)
                                               ,Y_train)
```

then model.fit

```
Classifier.fit(train_X,train_Y,batch_size = 100, epochs = 10
           ,validation_data= (test_X,test_Y),class_weight = class_weight )
```

Answer (score 6):

1- Define a dictionary with your labels and their associated weights

```
class_weight = {0: 0.1,
                1: 1.,
                2: 2.}
```

2- Feed the dictionary as a parameter:

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 100, epochs = 10, class_weight=class_weight)
```

Comment: classes are named from 0 or 1?

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking about the right weighting to apply or how to do that in the code? The code is simple:

```
class_weights = {}
    for i in range(2):
        class_weights[i] = your_weight
```

and then you pass the argument `class_weight=class_weights` in `model.fit`.

The right weighting to use would be some sort of inverse frequency; you can also do a bit of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

class weights takes a dictionary type.

```
from collections import Counter
itemCt = Counter(trainGen.classes)
maxCt = float(max(itemCt.values()))
cw = {clsID : maxCt/numImg for clsID, numImg in itemCt.items()}
```