# Does keras automatically weight classes?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

The [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/guides/training_with_built_in_methods/) states:

> ***Using sample weighting and class weighting***
>
> With the default settings the weight of a sample is decided by its frequency in the dataset. There are two methods to weight the data, independent of sample frequency:
> -Class weights
> -Sample weights

I have a significantly imbalanced dataset. I was looking at how to adjust for this, and came across a few answers here dealing with that, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716150/how-can-i-assign-a-class-weight-in-keras-in-a-simple-way) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586475/is-it-possible-to-automatically-infer-the-class-weight-from-flow-from-directory). My plan was thus to create a dictionary object of the relative frequencies and pass them onto `model.fit()`'s `class_weight` parameter.

However, now that I'm looking up the documentation, it seems as though class imbalance is already dealt with? So I don't necessarily have to manage for the different class counts after all?

For the record, here are the class counts:
`0`: 25,811,  `1`: 2,444,  `2`: 5,293,  `3`: 874,  `4`: 709.

And here is the dictionary I was going to pass onto (pseudocode):

```py
class_weight = {0: 1.0,
                1: len(/0/)/len(/1/),
                2: len(/0/)/len(/2/),
                3: len(/0/)/len(/3/),
                4: len(/0/)/len(/4/)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Model()` [class documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), the `model.fit()` has the following signature:

```
fit(
    x=None,
    y=None,
    batch_size=None,
    epochs=1,
    verbose='auto',
    callbacks=None,
    validation_split=0.0,
    validation_data=None,
    shuffle=True,
    class_weight=None,
    sample_weight=None,
    initial_epoch=0,
    steps_per_epoch=None,
    validation_steps=None,
    validation_batch_size=None,
    validation_freq=1,
    max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False
)
```

You can clearly notice that the `class_weight` parameter is `None`, by default.

The documentation also mentions that this is an optional parameter:

> Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight
> (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training
> only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to
> samples from an under-represented class.

Example (a mistake for `class_1` is penalized `10` times more than a mistake for `class_0`):

```
class_weight = {0:1,
                1:10}
```

**PS**: The statements are indeed a little bit misleading, in the sense that one can infer that if you have 2 classes with 90 and 10 samples respectively, the "weight" of the class is its number, but in fact what the explanation intends to convey is a synonym to saying "the model will not prioritize class 2 with 10 points over class 1 with 90 points, it's the overrepresentation of the latter (basic frequency) which counts more".

In other words, what it tells you is that the basic cross-entropy loss function (be it binary or multiclass) will favor the overrepresented class in absence of specific constraints/parameters from the developer.

This is indeed a correct affirmation, hence the necessity of tackling the imbalance via this class_weighting scheme in this situation.

Comment: How are these statements reconciled?

"With the default settings the weight of a sample is decided by its frequency in the dataset."

"You can clearly notice that the class_weight parameter is None, by default."

Does this mean that the default is 'None' because Keras is automatically applying weights based on the class counts? So I don't need to provide that optional dictionary (if the weights I want to provide are purely based on the class counts)?

The way I'm interpreting this optional parameter is if someone wanted to give weights based on some external criterion (and not counts)

Comment: First of all you are looking at plain Keras documentation, I strongly suggest that you switch to Keras inside TensorFlow (less prone to errors). The statements are indeed a little bit misleading, in the sense that it tells you that if you have 2 classes with 90 and 10 points respectively, the "weight" of the class is its number, which in fact is a synonym to saying "the model will not prioritize class 2 with 10 points over class 1 with 90 points, it's the overrepresentation of the latter (basic frequency) which counts more"

Comment: In other words, what it tells you is that the basic cross-entropy (be it binary or multiclass) will favor the overrepresented class in absence of specific inputs from the machine learning engineer (which in this case is the class_weight dictionary).

Comment: I can totally understand where the confusion comes from, I hope I made myself clear here.

Comment: I see! OK, so, I have to include a class_weight dictionary. It would have been helpful if they included an example of this, I haven't seen much reference to it in code examples. It seems like an important thing that should be referenced/covered a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you understand/solve your problem, please do upvote it. I have also updated it with a small example so that it can be better understood.

Comment: I will also update the answer with explanations from the comments above.