# How to balance data with keras.ImageDataGenerator()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, data-augmentation

Having unbalanced data, how can I use `ImageDataGenerator()` to generate enough augmented data for shorter sample to balance all categories?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `ImageDataGenerator`. There is simply no built-in option for that. However, you can use `class_weights` in `ft` method to somehow makeup for the contribution of low-count classes.

Comment: @today would you mind to provide a simple example.

Comment: This may be your solution.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586475/is-it-possible-to-automatically-infer-the-class-weight-from-flow-from-directory

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code,

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
```

This will not affect your dataset at all. It formats the image while feeding into the model. 
You may refer the documentation, [Image Preprocessing](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dictionary based on the weights of each class and then feed the model.fit_generator with it:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight import numpy as np

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
           'balanced',
            np.unique(train_generator.classes), 
            train_generator.classes)

train_class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
model.fit_generator(..., class_weight=train_class_weights)
```