# Imbalanced Image Dataset (Tensorflow2)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, imbalanced-data, image-classification, oversampling

I'm trying to do a binary image classification problem, but the two classes (~590 and ~5900 instances, for class 1 and 2, respectively) are heavily skewed, but still quite distinct.

Is there any way I can fix this, I want to try SMOTE/random weighted oversampling.

I've tried a lot of different things but I'm stuck. I've tried using `class_weights=[10,1]`,`[5900,590]`, and `[1/5900,1/590]` and my model still only predicts class 2.
I've tried using `tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets` but I couldn't get it to work. I've even tried using sigmoid focal cross-entropy loss, which helped a lot but not enough.

I want to be able to oversample class 1 by a factor of 10, the only thing I have tried that has kinda worked is manually oversampling i.e. copying the train dir's class 1 instances to match the number of instances in class 2.

Is there not an easier way of doing this, I'm using Google Colab and so doing this is extremely inefficient.

Is there a way to specify SMOTE params / oversampling within the data generator or similar?

```
data/
...class_1/
........image_1.jpg
........image_2.jpg
...class_2/
........image_1.jpg
........image_2.jpg
```

My data is in the form shown above.

```
TRAIN_DATAGEN = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.,
                                   rotation_range = 40,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   height_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

TEST_DATAGEN = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255.)

TRAIN_GENERATOR = TRAIN_DATAGEN.flow_from_directory(directory = TRAIN_DIR,
                                                    batch_size = BACTH_SIZE,
                                                    class_mode = 'binary', 
                                                    target_size = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                    subset = 'training',
                                                    seed = DATA_GENERATOR_SEED)

VALIDATION_GENERATOR = TEST_DATAGEN.flow_from_directory(directory = VALIDATION_DIR,
                                                        batch_size = BACTH_SIZE,
                                                        class_mode = 'binary', 
                                                        target_size = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                        subset = 'validation',
                                                        seed = DATA_GENERATOR_SEED)
...
...
...

HISTORY = MODEL.fit(TRAIN_GENERATOR,
                    validation_data = VALIDATION_GENERATOR,
                    epochs = EPOCHS,
                    verbose = 2,
                    callbacks = [EARLY_STOPPING],
                    class_weight = CLASS_WEIGHT)
```

I'm relatively new to Tensorflow but I have some experience with ML as a whole. I've been tempted to switch to PyTorch several times as they have params for data loaders that automatically (over/under)sample with `sampler=WeightedRandomSampler`.

Note: I've looked at many tutorials about how to oversample however none of them are image classification problems, I want to stick with TF/Keras as it allows for easy transfer learning, could you guys help out?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648129/balancing-an-imbalanced-dataset-with-keras-image-generator

Answer (score 3):

You can use this strategy to calculate weights based on the imbalance:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight 
import numpy as np

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
           'balanced',
            np.unique(train_generator.classes), 
            train_generator.classes)

train_class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
model.fit_generator(..., class_weight=train_class_weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can implement SMOTE using `imblearn` library as follows:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

oversample = SMOTE()
X, y = oversample.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Comment: I'm just very confused on how to get X and y in this case, can I extract it from the DataGen or do I need to parse the two folders for X?

Comment: @SakibAhamed Can you load the entire data to the ram? If yes, X and y are the features and labels of the entire data

Comment: There's far too much data to load into RAM, that's the real issue here - that's why I'm so set on using generators

Comment: @SakibAhamed in this case you can load data in batches using the generator and then oversample every batch to SMOTE before feeding them to the model.

Answer (score 0):

As you already define your `class_weight` as a dictionary, e.g., `{0: 10, 1: 1}`, you might try augmenting the minority class. See [balancing an imbalanced dataset with keras image generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648129/balancing-an-imbalanced-dataset-with-keras-image-generator) and the tutorial (that was mentioned there) at https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Comment: I typed it in wrong in my question, I do pass them in as a dictionary